# Are Python PEPs implemented as proposed/amended or is there wiggle room?

Tags: python, language-lawyer, standards, pep

I just noticed in PEP 3127 (the one that rationalised radix calculations on literals and `int()` arguments so that, for example, `010` is no longer a valid literal and must instead be `0o10` if octal is desired), that one particular part of the PEP was not implemented.

I refer specifically to the section quoted below:

> ***Tokenizer exception handling***
>
> If an invalid token contains a leading "0", the exception error message should be more informative than the current "SyntaxError: invalid token". It should explain that decimal numbers may not have a leading zero, and that octal numbers require an "o" after the leading zero.

However, when I try to use this (now invalid) format, I still see the old (less informative) error, as per the following transcript:

```
MyPromptHere> python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Oct  7 2019, 12:59:55) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = 010
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    x = 010
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid token

>>> int('010', 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 0: '010'

>>> _
```

Now I don't really *care* about the fact that it's a weird error since I earn much of my remuneration from arcane errors :-) However, from what I understand, the PEPs go through revision processes even *after* they've been sponsored so I'm curious as to why either:

- that part of the PEP wasn't implemented; or
- the PEP wasnt revised to reflect reality of the implementation.

Or is this simply the usage of the word "should" having less force than the normal standards "required" terms like "shall" or "must"? I'm not sure of that since, as per the transcript above, "should" appears to be obeyed in the section dealing with `int()`:

> ***`int()` exception handling***
>
> The `ValueError` raised for any call to `int()` with a string should at least explicitly contain the base in the error message, e.g.: `ValueError: invalid literal for base 8 int(): 09`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a python version difference for you.

```
Python 3.8.1 (default, Jan 13 2020, 22:28:48) 
>>> 010
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers
```

Also, in the "Open Issues" section of PEP 3127, it states

> There are still some strong feelings that '0123' should be allowed as
>   a literal decimal in Python 3.0. If this is the right thing to do,
>   this can easily be covered in an additional PEP. This proposal only
>   takes the first step of making '0123' not be a valid octal number, for
>   reasons covered in the rationale.

To me, this means that there was no hard requirement to change the error message. It was a suggestion to be more informative which was eventually implemented at some point (see 3.8.1 output above).

Comment: Good find. This appears to have been implemented as a separate bug fix (see, for example, https://bugs.python.org/issue20608), since doco as early as 3.0 states that the `0<digit>+` octal numbers are invalid. The better error messages appears to have show up somewhere after 3.6.8. In any case, the PEP changes made it illegal regardless of people's feelings on the matter so I would have thought the better error message would still be required. I can only assume the implementor was drunk at the time :-)

Comment: Jokes and sarcasm never go over well in text. You should consider avoiding it when complaining about volunteer contributions.